# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before '*' token Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Would anyone be kind enough to explain to me what I'm doing wrong. I'm giving it :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Product : NSObject {

    NSString *imageAddress;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *title;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) *imageAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) *product;

@end
```

and its giving me:

> Expected specifier-qualifier-list
>   before '*' token

for the property calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is gcc's cryptic way of telling you that you need a type for your properties.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product;
```

Comment: oh my. I've been staring at it for hours and didn't even realize. Many thanks.

Comment: A stated objective of clang is to provide more intuitive error messages. You might try switching the (even temporarily when gcc is being opaque).